# Prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{b(3+a-b)}\ge 1$

Tags: inequality

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive real numbers such that $a + b + c = 3$. Prove that

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b(3+a-b)}\ge1$$

I tried applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality by doing:

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b(3+a-b)}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{ab(3+a-b)}\ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum_{cyc}ab(3+a-b)}=\frac{9}{\sum_{cyc}ab(3+a-b)}.$$

We need therefore to prove that

$$\sum_{cyc}ab(3+a-b)\le 9.$$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You might want to explain the mathematical notation $\sum\limits_{cyc}$.

Comment: @barakmanos . $\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b(3+a-b)}=\frac{a}{b(3+a-b)}+\frac{b}{c(3+b-c)}+\frac{c}{a(3+c-a)}$

Answer (score 4):

By the AM-GM inequality we have
$$
3=3\root{3}\of{\frac{a}{b}\frac{b}{c}\frac{c}{a}}\leq \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\tag{1}
$$

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$
\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)^2\leq
\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b(2a+c)}\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{cyc}(2a+c)\right)\tag{2}
$$
But $$\sum_{cyc}(2a+c)=9\tag{3}$$ So combining $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get
$$1\leq \sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b(2a+c)}.$$
which is the same as the desired inequality since $2a+c=3+a-b~$.

Answer (score 0):

Your way works!

By C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b(3+a-b)}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b(2a+c)}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{ab(2a+c)}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}ab(2a+c)}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$(a+b+c)^3\geq3\sum\limits_{cyc}ab(2a+c)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3-3a^2b+3a^2c-abc)\geq0,$$ 
which is obvious.

Done!